# How to add a (primary) key to an existing table using SAP HANA

Tags: key, primary-key, hana, alter-table

What is the SQL command to add a (primary) key to a table in SAP HANA?

The [ALTER TABLE docu form SAP Library](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/d329a6751910149d5fdbc4800f92ff/content.htm#loio20d329a6751910149d5fdbc4800f92ff__sql_alter_table_1alter_table_add_column_clause) is cryptic to me

Comment: Just a note that if the table is already populated with data, you need to make sure that either you truncate the table and then add the new primary keys or you might want to drop the whole table and create that with new primary keys added.

Answer (score 10):

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table ADD PRIMARY KEY (column1,column2)
```

Comment: Got a sudden revelation about the documented syntax?

Answer (score 0):

For creating Primary key on existing table use the following syntax in SQL Console:

```
alter table "schemaName"."tableName" add constraint primary_key_alias Primary KEY("Column_Name");
```

Here primary_key_alias is the name for the primary key.
For more info goto:
[SAP help](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/d329a6751910149d5fdbc4800f92ff/content.htm)

Answer (score 0):

**To add constraints to a column:**

```
alter table "Schema_Name"."Table_Name"  add primary key ("Column_Name");
```